# Facebook API batch requests doesn't allow name parameter to be used as a label

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm building a batch request for the Facebook API by looping the following code:

```
//$fbid = a user's facebook id      
$query = array (
            'method' => "GET",
            //'name' => "{$fbid}",
            'relative_url' => '/'.$fbid.'/friends?fields=name,first_name,last_name,id,work,education&access_token='.$token
        );
```

This works fine. However, when I uncomment the third line with the `name =>` parameter, I get no data back. I've found numerous examples that do exactly this, so I can't figure out why it doesn't work.

The reason I need to add this field is because I need to associate the returned friends to the correct original user. This seemed like an easy way to do it, but I'm open to alternatives. Thanks!

UPDATE:
According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428923/linking-responses-to-requests-with-facebook-batch-requests) the API doesn't support the name parameter UNLESS you use it for assigning dependancies. So that would explain why my approach doesn't work... anyone have a solution that does work?

Comment: I’m only guessing, but since FQl involves JSON as data format in most cases, it _could_ be that a numeric id does not make for a valid name identifier. Try prefixing it with a letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this post the API doesn't support the name parameter UNLESS you use it for assigning dependancies. So that would explain why my approach doesn't work... anyone have a solution that does work?